# How to hide table before php search

Tags: php, mysql

Here is my code. before searching its showing entire table values. the search filter is working fine. but by default, I need to hide the table . 
**HTML Code:**

```
 <form id="form1" name="form1" method="post" action="search.php">
<label for="from">From</label>
<input name="from" type="text" id="from" size="10" value="<?php echo $_REQUEST["from"]; ?>" />
<label for="to">to</label>
<input name="to" type="text" id="to" size="10" value="<?php echo $_REQUEST["to"]; ?>"/>
 <label>Name or Email:</label>
<input type="text" name="string" id="string" value="<?php echo stripcslashes($_REQUEST["string"]); ?>" />
<label>City</label>
<select name="city">
<option value="">--</option>
<?php
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM ".$SETTINGS["data_table"]." GROUP BY city ORDER BY city";
    $sql_result = mysql_query ($sql, $connection ) or die ('request "Could not execute SQL query" '.$sql);
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($sql_result)) {
        echo "<option value='".$row["city"]."'".($row["city"]==$_REQUEST["city"] ? " selected" : "").">".$row["city"]."</option>";
    }
?>
</select>
<input type="submit" name="button" id="button" value="Filter" />
  </label>
      </form>
```

**PHP Code:**

```
<table width="700" border="1" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="4">
  <tr>
    <td width="90" bgcolor="#CCCCCC"><strong>From date</strong></td>
    <td width="95" bgcolor="#CCCCCC"><strong>To date</strong></td>
    <td width="159" bgcolor="#CCCCCC"><strong>Name</strong></td>
    <td width="191" bgcolor="#CCCCCC"><strong>Email</strong></td>
    <td width="113" bgcolor="#CCCCCC"><strong>City</strong></td>
  </tr>
<?php
if ($_REQUEST["string"]<>'') {
    $search_string = " AND (full_name LIKE '%".mysql_real_escape_string($_REQUEST["string"])."%' OR email LIKE '%".mysql_real_escape_string($_REQUEST["string"])."%')"; 
}
if ($_REQUEST["city"]<>'') {
    $search_city = " AND city='".mysql_real_escape_string($_REQUEST["city"])."'";   
}

if ($_REQUEST["from"]<>'' and $_REQUEST["to"]<>'') {
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM ".$SETTINGS["data_table"]." WHERE from_date >= '".mysql_real_escape_string($_REQUEST["from"])."' AND to_date <= '".mysql_real_escape_string($_REQUEST["to"])."'".$search_string.$search_city;
} else if ($_REQUEST["from"]<>'') {
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM ".$SETTINGS["data_table"]." WHERE from_date >= '".mysql_real_escape_string($_REQUEST["from"])."'".$search_string.$search_city;
} else if ($_REQUEST["to"]<>'') {
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM ".$SETTINGS["data_table"]." WHERE to_date <= '".mysql_real_escape_string($_REQUEST["to"])."'".$search_string.$search_city;
} else {
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM ".$SETTINGS["data_table"]." WHERE id>0".$search_string.$search_city;
}

$sql_result = mysql_query ($sql, $connection ) or die ('request "Could not execute SQL query" '.$sql);
if (mysql_num_rows($sql_result)>0) {
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($sql_result)) {
?>
  <tr>
    <td><?php echo $row["from_date"]; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $row["to_date"]; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $row["full_name"]; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $row["email"]; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $row["city"]; ?></td>
  </tr>
<?php
    }
} else {
?>
<tr><td colspan="5">No results found.</td>
<?php   
}
?>
</table>
```

The code is working fine. how to hide the table before submitting the search button in php and mysql. If anyone knows please answer my ques.

Comment: `mysql_*` is deprecated, you should use `mysqli`_ or PDO prepared statements. Also your code is vulnerable to SQL injections, better start from here. You could use `if(isset($_REQUEST['string'])` before your table if you want to display it after your submit.

Comment: I agree with @D.Dimitrov about his suggestions. Regardless, to "hide the table" you can simply wrap the whole table in a condition that tests the search post.

Comment: Ya. PDO we can use. but in this tool, they already coded with MySQL. so I just add that condition in MySQL only. I got the solution. I added if(isset($_POST['button'])) before the  table. So, table will show after submitting the form.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the solution.

I added

```
if(isset($_POST['button']))
```

before the table. So, table will show after submitting the form.

Answer (score 0):

```
**<?php
error_reporting(0);
include("config.php");
?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>MySQL table search</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.16/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<link href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
<style>
BODY, TD {
    font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size:12px;
}
</style>
</head>


<body>

<form id="form1" name="form1" method="post" action="search.php">
<label for="from">From</label>
<input name="from" type="text" id="from" size="10" value="<?php echo $_REQUEST["from"]; ?>" />
<label for="to">to</label>
<input name="to" type="text" id="to" size="10" value="<?php echo $_REQUEST["to"]; ?>"/>
 <label>Name or Email:</label>
<input type="text" name="string" id="string" value="<?php echo stripcslashes($_REQUEST["string"]); ?>" />
<label>City</label>
<select name="city">
<option value="">--</option>
<?php
    $sql_result = mysqli_query($connection,"SELECT * FROM data GROUP BY city ORDER BY city");
    //echo "SELECT * FROM data GROUP BY city ORDER BY city";

    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($sql_result)) {
        echo "<option value='".$row["city"]."'".($row["city"]==$_REQUEST["city"] ? " selected" : "").">".$row["city"]."</option>";
    }
?>
</select>
<input type="submit" name="button" id="button" value="Filter" />
  </label>
  <a href="search.php"> 
  reset</a>
</form>
<br /><br />
<table width="700" border="1" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="4">
  <tr>
    <td width="90" bgcolor="#CCCCCC"><strong>From date</strong></td>
    <td width="95" bgcolor="#CCCCCC"><strong>To date</strong></td>
    <td width="159" bgcolor="#CCCCCC"><strong>Name</strong></td>
    <td width="191" bgcolor="#CCCCCC"><strong>Email</strong></td>
    <td width="113" bgcolor="#CCCCCC"><strong>City</strong></td>
  </tr>
<?php
//echo $_REQUEST["string"];
if ($_REQUEST["string"]<>'') {
    $search_string = " AND (full_name LIKE '%".mysqli_real_escape_string($_REQUEST["string"])."%' OR email LIKE '%".mysqli_real_escape_string($_REQUEST["string"])."%')";   
    echo $search_string;
}
if ($_REQUEST["city"]<>'') {
    $search_city = " AND city='".mysqli_real_escape_string($_REQUEST["city"])."'";  
}

if ($_REQUEST["from"]<>'' and $_REQUEST["to"]<>'') {
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM data WHERE from_date >= '".mysqli_real_escape_string($_REQUEST["from"])."' AND to_date <= '".mysql_real_escape_string($_REQUEST["to"])."'".$search_string.$search_city;
} else if ($_REQUEST["from"]<>'') {
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM data WHERE from_date >= enter code here'".mysqli_real_escape_string($_REQUEST["from"])."'".$search_string.$search_city;
} else if ($_REQUEST["to"]<>'') {
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM data WHERE to_date <= '".mysqli_real_escape_string($_REQUEST["to"])."'".$search_string.$search_city;
} else {
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM data WHERE id>0".$search_string.$search_city;
}

$sql_result = mysqli_query ($sql, $connection ) or die ('request "Could not execute SQL query" '.$sql);
if (mysql_num_rows($sql_result)>0) {
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($sql_result)) {
?>
  <tr>
    <td><?php echo $row["from_date"]; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $row["to_date"]; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $row["full_name"]; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $row["email"]; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $row["city"]; ?></td>
  </tr>
<?php
    }
} else {
?>
<tr><td colspan="5">No results found.</td>
<?php   
}
?>
</table>


<script>
    $(function() {
        var dates = $( "#from, #to" ).datepicker({
            defaultDate: "+1w",
            changeMonth: true,
            numberOfMonths: 2,
            dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd',
            onSelect: function( selectedDate ) {
                var option = this.id == "from" ? "minDate" : "maxDate",
                    instance = $( this ).data( "datepicker" ),
                    date = $.datepicker.parseDate(
                        instance.settings.dateFormat ||
                        $.datepicker._defaults.dateFormat,
                        selectedDate, instance.settings );
                dates.not( this ).datepicker( "option", option, date );
            }
        });
    });
    </script>

</body>
</html>**
```